# Where does Digest::SHA2.hexdigest() defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sha, digest

I'm following through the tutorial from the book [Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549) and I found the following code:

```
def User.encrypt_password(password, salt) 
  Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(password + "wibble" + salt)
end
```

Looking into the `Digest` source code (`digest.rb` and `digest/sha2.rb` inside the `lib` directory in my ruby installation), however, I can't seem to find where the `hexdigest` method is defined, but yet the code seems to work just fine.

Can someone enlighten me how this happens? I assume that I need to look for a code that somehow looks like:

```
def hexdigest(...)
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `hexdigest` part, and several other similar methods are written as a C extension for speed. It's found in `ext/digest/` in the Ruby source.

`static VALUE rb_digest_instance_hexdigest(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)` is defined on line 216 in `ext/digest/digest.c` in my Ruby 1.9.2-p0 source. It just calls a bunch of other functions, but it might be a starting point at least.

For SHA2, there is another `ext/digest/sha2/sha2.c` that contains those functions. `digest.c` is just the basics, "extended" by the other ones

Answer (score 2):

According to http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/digest/rdoc/classes/Digest/Class.html

Digest is implemented in digest.rb and also digest.c (native methods). I believe what is happening here is hexdigest is a class method on Digest which Digest::SHA2 inherits. The implementation of hexdigest calls the digest class method which each digest type implements and returns the result.